# How to give WHERE condition in pg_dump?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin, dump

How to give WHERE condition in pg_dump to extract for particular values in below command,

```
pg_dump --table=export_table --data-only --column-inserts my_database > data.sql
```

Comment: `pg_dump` dumps databases; if you want to extract data use a query.

Comment: This question makes no sense. `pg_dump` is a command line backup tool. `WHERE` is a  clause in the SQL language. Clarify your objective, please. And *always* disclose your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 5):

Postgres does not have any `--` flag to filter the data you want to extract from a `--table`.

The best way you can do this is probably to select the data you want to extract with a query and then to save it into a csv.

then you can export that csv wherever you want and import the data back into a table having the same structure of the source table.

e.g.

let's suppose the data you want to dump are selected by the following query:

```
select * from my_table where date>=current_date-7;
```

access the source database and save tha desired data into a csv

```
\COPY (select * from my_table where date>=current_date-7) TO '~/my_local_path/dump_mydb_7daysdata.csv';
```

transfer the csv file (if you wish to)

```
scp ~/my_local_path/dump_mydb_7daysdata.csv <user>@<ip>:~/my_path_2/
```

access another database and import the data from the csv file

```
\COPY my_table_2 FROM '~/my_path_2/dump_mydb_7daysdata.csv';
```

Again, note that `my_table` and `my_table_2` must have the same structure.

Addition:

If you want to define the delimiter and add the header

**copy to**

```
\COPY (select * from my_table where date>=current_date-7) TO '~/my_local_path/dump_mydb_7daysdata.csv' with delimiter ';' CSV HEADER;
```

**copy from**

```
\COPY my_table_2 FROM '~/my_path_2/dump_mydb_7daysdata.csv' with delimiter ';' CSV HEADER;
```

Comment: > with the same structure of the source table; does this command handle the creation of the table with the same structure when you restore it as CSV?

Comment: @kennysliding no, it only uploads the data into an already exisitng table on the destination DB, having the same structure of the table in the source DB.